# Как задать тегам "a" (баттонам) стиль списка?

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу из этих тегов "а" переделанных под баттоны сделать список. Как то стрёмно и хаотично они стоят. 
Вот и код мой

```
<div class="col-12 xl-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3" id="group_all class="brd8">
  <a href="{{route('home')}}"  id="group_all" class="brd8">
    <i class="fas fa-users">
    </i> 
    {{trans('main.all')}}
  </a>
  @foreach($groups as $group)
    <a href="#" onclick="select_group({{$group->id}})" id="{{$group->id}}" class="brd8">
    <i class="fas fa-users">
    </i> 
    {{$group->name}}
   </a>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Вот кавычки не хватает `id="group_all class="brd8"` после group_all, может поэтому все поплыло?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, а Вас не смущает, что один и тот же id на странице?

Comment: @humster_spb смущает, но я же не знаю задумку автора? Начнем с кавычки ))

Comment: @Akina я ничего не правил, только добавил тэг bootsrap и думаю, какой шаблонизатор он использует?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Аааа... просто вижу - Вы последний корректировали, и кавычка появилась... ну тады прошу пардону.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin кавычки тут выпали но в проекте на месте. Видимо проблема в другом чём то

Comment: Может быть в этом https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/list-group/

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо проблема решена)))